# Correct standard to do a pull request when the local branch is outdated against the remote repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci, git-branch, git-pull

The scenario is the following:

For a project, such as *Spring Security* available on github, the following is accomplished:

- forked and cloned
- `git remote add upstream URL-Remote-Repository`
- `git fetch upstream`
- In *master* branch `git merge upstream/master`

It for the first time and all work fine.

A new branch is created to fix or add something - `git checkout -b gh-150` was executed (and none `git commit` was executed yet), it takes some days to complete the job, once completed, prior to execute `git commit` (the first execution of that command for that branch), I confirm that in the passed days in the original (remote) repository code changed

What is the correct approach to fetch the new code from the remote repository into the master and avoiding lost any data from the local branch? It with the purpose to send a pull request to the server in peace later. Therefore the goal is, keep the new code of the local branch, get the new code from the master (without lost any data) and send in peace the pull request to the server.

Even if I do the commit in my local branch and return to the master, do the fetch and merge, my local branch is not updated against the master yet. If I return to my local branch and try to merge from the master to my local branch I would lost the updated code (of course, if the same components were edited)

Let say the ideal scenario should be the same as follows:

- I create the new branch and edited my changes
- I confirmed that in that days there are no changes in the remote repository, so is not need it do a fetch and merge - so the new changes exists only by my side
- so I can send the pull request in peace

**Consideration: *(not close this post)***: I know that git and github are available since years ago, but I am assuming that exists a standard (mostly a new or current standard/approach) to handle in peace this scenario without risk to lost any data by mistake - it such as *the best practices according the experiences throughout these years*.

Comment: “Therefore the goal is, keep the new code of the local branch, get the new code from the master (without lost any data) and send in peace the pull request to the server.” Stay on local branch, fetch from upstream, then rebase on top of upstream/master (resolving conflicts as needed) and push and create pull request out of branch.

Comment: @matt your comment has sense, if you can post an answer listing each point through a bullet point  (and showing the command) would be nice, and indicating for each point in what branch the developer should be located

Comment: "best practice" type answers drag in opinions, and for that reason, are usually redirected to places like softwareengineering.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I think is: 'https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com'

Answer (score 1):

"If I return to my local branch and try to merge from the master to my local branch I would lost the updated code (of course, if the same components were edited)" --> You won't lose them, a **merge** will apply the new modifications from master on a **new commit** in your branch it's transparent if there isn't any **conflict**, you can also do it directly in the pull request (or with the command `git merge master`)

Alternatively there is the option to rebase your branch with master with the main advantage of having your branch on the same **history line** as master (which is great if you want your master branch to have an history without any merge commit). The cost is that the new commits from master can appear on your branch and make it a bit less clear.

To rebase it's very straightforward:

- `git checkout yourbranch`
- `git rebase master` -- here git will prompt you to resolve all conflicts

I think the best practice would be to rebase from master but it really depends on your use case.